# Как убрать elevation у DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Добавил в свой проект `DrawerLayout` но при свайпе у него есть `elevation` как его убрать?

Пробовал добавлять `app:elevation="0dp"`, не работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно написать в файле где находиться `DrawerLayout` следующие

```
DrawerLayout drawer_layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer_layout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
drawer_layout.setDrawerElevation(0);
```